# Creating new variables in Abaqus

Tags: fortran, subroutine, abaqus

Here is what I like to do in Abaqus (if possible):

As a minimum working example, let's say I have an elastic specimen that I am applying a load on. When I look at the results I can see S11, S22, S33, etc...

What I would like to see are things like S11-S22, S11-S12 and the like. Is that possible? I know that `UMAT` is a thing and I have the elastic code from the documentation working. Can I define S11-S22 in there and return it? If so, how?

I know Fortran, it's Abaqus I'm iffy with.

Comment: Is the data necessery in the calculation (for example for a material model) or do you only need the data after the calculation?

Comment: If you are already using a UMAT you can return whatever you want as solution dependent variables.  However you do not need to use a UMAT just for that purpose. If you want to plot such things you can create simple computed fields in the GUI post process.

Comment: right now I only need to look at the data (as in not used in any calculations). How do I create computed stress fields? I know there's a 'create field output' under 'tools', but I don't how to tell it to do S11-S22 for example.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! For anyone else looking in the future... In Tools > Create Field Output > From Fields go to the frame you want and scroll down the list to find the stress tensor (will have a name like s1f5_S for stress components). Over on the right side, the drop down menu for functions can be changed to scalars, clicking on s1f5 (or whatever) will give you the option of selecting the component you want.